# Gradients are None when using tf.function decorator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to migrate my code to tensorflow 2.0 but I have trouble with the tf.function to create explicit graphs. In particular, given the following model:

```py
def new_dueling_model(name, input_size, output_size):
    states = tf.keras.Input(shape=(input_size,))
    h1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(states)

    # State value function
    value_h2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(h1)
    value_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(value_h2)

    # Advantage function
    advantage_h2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(h1)
    advantage_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size)(advantage_h2)

    outputs = value_output + (advantage_output - tf.reduce_mean(advantage_output, axis=1, keepdims=True))

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=states, outputs=outputs, name=name)

    return model
```

And the following function to train it:

```py
def q_train(states, actions, targets, is_weights, model, output_size, learning_rate, clip_grad):
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=learning_rate)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        outputs = model(states)
        q_values = tf.multiply(outputs, (tf.one_hot(tf.squeeze(actions), output_size)))

        loss_value = tf.reduce_mean(is_weights * tf.losses.mean_squared_error(targets, q_values))


    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)

    selected_q_values = tf.reduce_sum(q_values, axis=1)
    selected_targets = tf.reduce_sum(targets, axis=1)
    td_errors = tf.clip_by_value(selected_q_values - selected_targets, -1.0, 1.0)

    if clip_grad:
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([tf.clip_by_value(grad, -1.0, 1.0) for grad in grads], model.trainable_variables))
    else:
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

    return td_errors
```

I have the following call in my main loop to train the model:

```py
   # states, actions, targets and is_weights are numpy arrays
   # model is created using new_dueling_model
   td_errors = q_train(states, actions, targets, is_weights, model, num_actions, 0.00025, False)
   # ...
```

Everything works and, as expected, comparing it with tf1.x code, the train step is much slower. Hence, I decorated the q_train function to have a high-performant tf graph. However now, every time I call the function, the grads are always None.

```py
@tf.function
def q_train(...):
    # ...
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
    # grads here are None
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.
First I installed the nightly package using:

```
pip install tf-nightly-2.0-preview
```

At this point, after running the code the following error came up:

```
ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call
```

I solved this new error by creating the optimizer

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=learning_rate)
```

outside the @tf.function decorated function, and everything worked as expected.